# Unable to setup a user adminstrator account in mongodb running on fedora

Tags: mongodb

I have setup mongodb by downloading the 64 bit legacy linux download on the official mongodb website.I started the mongod service, and then installed the mean stack by following the instructions on the meanjs.org website. I started the server and the default boilerplate of meanjs showed up. Now I am trying to setup the user adminstrator for the mongodb server. There was no admin database by default, so I tried the following:

```
use admin
db.createUser({
user:”siteUserAdmin”,
pwd: “useradminpwd”
roles: [{role: “userAdminAnyDatabase”,db: “admin”}]
})
```

I am getting the following error:E QUERY    SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
There was also a `mean-dev` database with the following collections:`sessions, system.indexes, users` so I also tried creating the user adminstrator account in this database and I got the same error.I need guidance to setup the user adminstrator account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check `mongod.conf` and set

```
auth=true
```

After that, restart `mongod`.

Now you need to use the mongo shell on the server `mongod` is running on.

Your statements look correct, but for completeness:

```
use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "siteUserAdmin",
    pwd: "yourPassword",
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
  }
)
```